# Accurate P2P time synchronization between devices

Tags: p2p, ntp

I need to synchronize devices connected to each other over an unknown (wireless) network. The accuracy required is high (better than the network latency gives me) and it needs to be robust even in case of wireless interference. I am thinking about implementing NTP (or a homebrew solution ripping the core algorithm out of it), but it is client/server based. Is there an obvious solution I am overlooking in the P2P case?

What I expect to end up with is a list of delta-t's (difference in hardware clock) for each peer (on each device), so that each device knows when something on another device happened.

Language or framework does not matter so much for me right now, but the end solution will run on iOS and Android.

Comment: Have you come up with a solution for this? I am looking to do something very similar for both iOS and Android

Comment: Not a good one. I have a small toy project that is put on hold awaiting a good solution to this :)

Comment: I spoke with someone the other day on how I might be able to do this, I'm working on a token solution (nothing robust by any means) however, this is where I'm starting http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html